# Laravel Many to Many eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to hide a columns on many to many relationships, but no success for now.
I have:

**Square.php**

```
public function sitesquares() { 
     //Trying to use select() but no success 
    return $this->belongsToMany('Sitesquare', 'square_site', 'square_id', 'site_id')->select( array('square_id','site_id', 'sites.site_name') ); 
}
```

**Sitesquare.php**

```
public function squares() 
{ 
    return $this->belongsToMany('Square', 'square_site'); 
}
```

**Square Controller**

```
 $sites = Square::with(array('sitesquares'=>function ($q)
 { 
    $q->select(array('site_name')); //also don't work

 }))->get();

 return $sites; //json
```

someone please, any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, on your model, any columns you wish to remain hidden should be added to the hidden array.

```
protected $hidden = array('password');
```

Comment: but in another situation I don't need hide.. have I how to change dynamically?